# Accessing a the click() slot of a button generated during runtime - Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, signals-slots

I have a GUI project in Qt Creator that functions as a shopping list. I am using a QLineEdit to add items to a QTableWidget. The user types something in, presses the QPushButton. The slot then adds a new row to the QTableWidget with the input, in the first column, and a new QPushButton in the second column. I then want the user to be able to press the button and have it clear that row, but I don't know how to access that slot, or sender (I'm not sure the proper term.) Here is the code so far. `itemList` is my QTableWidget, `itemInput` is the QLineEdit.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnAddItem_clicked()
{
    ui->itemList->insertRow(ui->itemList->rowCount());
    ui->itemList->setItem((ui->itemList->rowCount())-1,0,new QTableWidgetItem(ui->itemInput->text()));
    QPushButton *clear = new QPushButton("Clear",this);
    ui->itemList->setIndexWidget(ui->itemList->model()->index(ui->itemList->rowCount()-1, 1), clear);
    ui->itemInput->clear();
}
```

Here is when the program is initially run. Once they click the button, it runs `on_btnAddItem_clicked()`

[image: initial run]

Then it looks like this, and I want to make the clear button remove the row it is a part of.

[image: table entry]

Do I need to create a new slot? Any help?

Comment: ***Do I need to create a new slot?*** Yes if you don't have one. I see you are creating the new button but not connecting its `clicked()` signal to a slot in MainWindow. Also don't use the `on_` naming convention for the new slot  you create since this will not be an automatic connection.

Comment: @drescherjm, from my understanding, he/she is trying to connect the `clicked()` signal to a certain slot of the `QTableWidget` (or its model or delegate?) with a corresponding `QTableWidgetItem` as input parameter so that it is possible to edit/erase the content of that `QTableWidgetItem`. The signal `clicked()` is only able to pass `bool` as parameter, so how would they access which row to erase. Does it sound right ?

Comment: No no, the clicked() signal I already have adds the user input to the table along with a new PushButton in the same row. I then want the user to be able to push the button and have it clear the row. That way, they can delete entries from the table. But I cannot pre-create the rows and buttons because I don't know how many entries a user will enter, so I'm not sure how to make a button do something if it doesn't exist until the program is running.

Comment: I made edits to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @Kenta, I referred to the signal `clicked()` of `QPushButton` that you create dynamically which is called "Clear" on your screenshot. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @vicru Yes that makes sense. Can I not return the row of the button that was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your own button class and inherit QPushButton. Something like this :

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton {
    public:
    MyButton();
    QTableWidgetItem *titem;
}
```

And here you MainWindow :

```
void MainWindow::on_btnAddItem_clicked()
{
    ui->itemList->insertRow(ui->itemList->rowCount());
    ui->itemList->setItem((ui->itemList->rowCount())-1,0,new QTableWidgetItem(ui->itemInput->text()));
    MyButton *clear = new MyButton("Clear",this);
    clear->titem = ui->itemList->item(ui->itemList->rowCount()-1, 0);
    connect(clear, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(on_btnClear_Clicked()));
    ui->itemList->setIndexWidget(ui->itemList->model()->index(ui->itemList->rowCount()-1, 1), clear);
    ui->itemInput->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_btnClear_Clicked()
{
    MyButton *btn = (MyButton*)QObject::sender();
    ui->itemList->removeRow(btn->titem->row());
}
```

Please note, it is only step to do it.

Comment: It would be better to use `qobject_cast<MyButton *>(QObject::sender())` instead.